# How did my soul end up in the cycle of samsara?

Tags: hinduism

I experienced ego death today. Sorry if my terminology is wrong. But i saw the way. I just want to understand now

Comment: This is not a Hindu site

Comment: I guess Sankha might be saying that because Buddhism doesn't teach that there is a "my soul" (see the "anatta" docrtine).

Comment: Soul is perhaps mistaken for the continuation of the six sense doors. There is a stream of sensory information that you possess that is not confined to your own sensory experience. It's a collective of many sensate events from previous six sense doors and is often confused for harbouring a static nature, for example: a soul.

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhism, to have realisation, what must be experienced is ego death = peace. Sometimes ego death is not peaceful. If it is experienced ego death = peace then the way is known and continued.

As for the word "samsara", it means for the mind to "cycle" around in egoism. It is not related to "reincarnation", as explained below:

> *At Savatthi. There the Blessed One said: "Monks, from an inconstruable beginning comes samsara. A beginning point is not
> evident, although beings hindered by ignorance and fettered by craving
> are running around & wandering on.*
>
> *Just as a dog, tied by a leash to a post or stake, keeps running around and circling around that very post or stake; in the same way,
> an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person — who has no regard for noble
> ones, is not well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma; who has no
> regard for people of integrity, is not well-versed or disciplined in
> their Dhamma — assumes form to be the self, or the self as possessing
> form, or form as in the self, or the self as in form.*
>
> *"He assumes feeling to be the self...*
>
> *"He assumes perception to be the self...*
>
> *"He assumes (mental) fabrications to be the self...*
>
> *"He assumes consciousness to be the self, or the self as possessing consciousness, or consciousness as in the self, or the self as in
> consciousness.*
>
> *"He keeps running around and circling around that very form... that very feeling... that very perception... those very fabrications...
> that very consciousness. He is not set loose from form, not set loose
> from feeling... from perception... from fabrications... not set loose
> from consciousness. He is not set loose from birth, aging, & death;
> from sorrows, lamentations, pains, distresses, & despairs. He is not
> set loose, I tell you, from suffering & stress.*
>
> *But a well-instructed, disciple of the noble ones — who has regard for noble ones, is well-versed & disciplined in their Dhamma; who has
> regard for people of integrity, is well-versed & disciplined in their
> Dhamma — doesn't assume form to be the self, or the self as possessing
> form, or form as in the self, or the self as in form.*
>
> *"He doesn't assume feeling to be the self...*
>
> *"He doesn't assume perception to be the self...*
>
> *"He doesn't assume fabrications to be the self...*
>
> *"He doesn't assume consciousness to be the self, or the self as possessing consciousness, or consciousness as in the self, or the self
> as in consciousness.*
>
> *"He doesn't run around or circle around that very form... that very feeling... that very perception... those very fabrications... that
> very consciousness. He is set loose from form, set loose from
> feeling... from perception... from fabrications... set loose from
> consciousness. He is set loose from birth, aging, & death; from
> sorrows, lamentations, pains, distresses, & despairs. He is set loose,
> I tell you, from suffering & stress.*
>
> [*SN 22.99*](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.099.than.html)